# Bind id to Angular mat-checkbox

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to bind id to Angular material checkbox.
I have an object item.
When I inspect html I have item.id + '-input'
But when I bind name it's okay: item.id

This is my code:

```
<mat-checkbox [id]="item.id"[name]="item.id">
```

Answer (score 0):

i havent worked with Material yet but in native angular you can assign IDs via a component by   *[id]="{{item.id}}"*.
If your using an obejct array[] of items, you can also try iterating through your array to create Mutliple entrys like so.

```
<div class="subbox text-center"
     *ngFor="let i of item">
  <mat-checkbox [id]="{{i.id}}" [name]="{{i.name}}">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need interpolation there if you are using brackets for id.